# Converting variable length time-series into constant length

Tags: statistics, interpolation, time-series

I have a set of time series that are of variable length. I intend to bring them to a particular length (preferably the median length) in order to analyze them. I was hoping that I could get some techniques to do the same.

P.S - I heard that interpolation works well for such kinds of problems. Would interpolation allow me to reduce the length of the time-series, for instance bring the longest time series to median length?

Comment: It depends what “length” means. If they are all time series over the same time range, but the frequency of sampling differs, then you could interpolate so they have readings at the same intervals. If they are over different ranges, I’m not sure what you would be trying to do.

That said, what methods of analysis are appropriate at all depend strongly on the context and on your model. You might have more luck if you provided more context, and you might also consider asking at stats.stackexchange.com, since while interpolation is mathematics, your application is statistical.

Comment: I don't have any more context to add. Essentially, I am work with variable length time series, which is a pain when I use python libraries. I want to bring them to the same length, so that it'll allow for easy computation.

Comment: You must have context. Consider two examples: 1. Series 1a: Daily temperatures in location X for January, 2019; Series 1b: Daily temperatures in location Y for the first 3 months of 2019. 2. Series 2a: Daily temperatures in location X for January 2019. Series 2b: Hourly temperatures in location Y for January 2019. For 1., you would bring them to the same length by throwing out data past January from series b. For 2., you could choose one point per day from 2b, or you could interpolate 2a (which yields implausible hourly data). There is no answer from the limited information you give.